# How to check that notifications are enabled on iPhone

Tags: iphone, xcode, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

How to check that notification is enabled on iPhone?
I install the application, application say to confirm enable push notification for application, i click ok. But if notification disabled on iPhone, this action does not enable notifications.
How to check that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This should work:

```
UIRemoteNotificationType types = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] enabledRemoteNotificationTypes];
if (types == UIRemoteNotificationTypeNone) 
   // Disabled
```

Answer (score 3):

This changed in iOS8. To support both iOS8 and lower do

```
+ (BOOL)notificationServicesEnabled {
    BOOL isEnabled = NO;

    if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] respondsToSelector:@selector(currentUserNotificationSettings)]){
        UIUserNotificationSettings *notificationSettings = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] currentUserNotificationSettings];

        if (!notificationSettings || (notificationSettings.types == UIUserNotificationTypeNone)) {
            isEnabled = NO;
        } else {
            isEnabled = YES;
        }
    } else {
        UIRemoteNotificationType types = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] enabledRemoteNotificationTypes];
        if (types & UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert) {
            isEnabled = YES;
        } else{
            isEnabled = NO;
        }
    }

    return isEnabled;
}
```

Comment: Are you putting this in the `AppDelegate` or the `ViewController`?

Comment: You could put this snippet anywhere since it grabs data from singleton objects. Personally speaking, I put the code in a `DeviceNotificationsManager` Class, which encapsulates logic relevant to the phone's notification subsystem. That way the outside world (i.e the rest of the app) only references `DeviceNotificationsManager` and doesn't have to know about the iOS's notification system in any detail.

Comment: Hey @ShaheenGhiassy,The above snippet works. Is there any specific reason for inverting the logic for the if & else part. In the if section we check for UIUserNotificationTypeNone while in else we are checking it for UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert.